# How to use each date from database as table headers in laravel blade

Tags: php, html, laravel

In my database i have table called **signal**  with this structure

| Id | date | status | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2/12/2023 | 1 | ben |
| 2 | 2/12/2023 | 1 | john |
| 3 | 3/12/2023 | 1 | peter |
| 4 | 3/12/2023 | 1 | love |
| 5 | 3/12/2023 | 1 | sad |
| 6 | 4/12/2023 | 1 | water |
| 7 | 4/12/2023 | 1 | tom |
| 8 | 5/12/2023 | 1 | jerry |
| 9 | 5/12/2023 | 1 | hen |
| 10 | 5/12/2023 | 1 | bete |

From my controller i have gotten the needed data
`$history = Signal::where('status', 1)->paginate(getPaginate(7));`

I can show the value on a table normally but what i want is

`for each date, create a table with that date as the header`  just like the tables below

```
                 **2/12/2023**
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ben |
| 2 | john |

```
                **3/12/2023**
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | peter |
| 4 | love |
| 5 | sad |

```
              **4/12/2023**
```

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 6 | water |
| 7 | tom |

I have tried to make a normal table but i don't know how to do this with dynamic headers

Comment: It can be achieved but having IDs the way you want them to be is not a good approach. You can use separate auto increment id numbers for each table starting with ID 1, 2 etc...looks more better. This is if the table is one.

Comment: @BrianMweu _"You can use separate auto increment id numbers for each table"_ - I am pretty sure they are _not_ talking about three different database tables here; they want the result from their _one_ database table, displayed in three separate _HTML_ tables.

Comment: This is a classic _control break_ scenario. You loop over your properly ordered data, and compare the date of each record, with that of the previous one. Based on whether they are the same or differ - you need to react accordingly. (I.e., here, keep creating a new table row to add to the current table - or close the current table, and open a new one first, before you write out the next table row.)

Comment: @CBroe Yes that's what he wants. As I said if it's one database Table!. It can be achieved since for instance if it's one database table we know the ID is going to be auto increment. But you can use something like a separate number 'ID' which will be separate from your usual auto increment ID's of your one database table. It's something I have done before!

Comment: Why would you need a separate ID for this?
If you fetch all rows ordered by date, create a new array where each date is a key and all the statuses and names for that date will be contained in an array as its value, it will basically already work

Comment: @BrianMweu _"But you can use something like a separate number 'ID' which will be separate from your usual auto increment ID's of your one database table."_ - well sure you _could_, only that's not what anyone asked for here, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Laravel's [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/collections#method-groupby) method, like this:

```
$results = Signal::where('status', 1)
    ->paginate(getPaginate(7))
    ->groupBy('date');
```

This will return all the results grouped by the same date, in a format:

```
results = [
    date1 => [
        item1, 
        item2,
        //etc
    ],
    date2 => [
        item3,
        item4,
        //etc
    ]
]
```

Then in blade, you can loop through these results like this:

```
@foreach ($results as $date => $items)
    <p>Date: {{$date}}</p>

    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <td>name</td>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        @foreach ($items as $item)
            <tr>{{$item->id}}</tr>
            <tr>{{$item->name}}</tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
@endforeach
```

Note: Table layout not tested, but you get the general idea.